# Qual è il significato di "aggrettato"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Rinascimento privato* di Maria Bellonci ho letto:

> Forse allude alla corona immaginaria l'acconciatura che sto inventando, una capigliatura 
>   che andrà poi per il mondo imitata da tutte le donne. Le prime volte che la porto nei miei 
>   ricevimenti di capo di stato suscita qualche incertezza; siamo troppo abituati alle pettinature lisce o **aggrettate**, di capelli disciolti o a testina raccolta con la treccia o la mezza treccia ricadente sulla schiena. Io impongo un altro modo di apparire con questa foggia che ha del turbante e del diadema.

Ho cercato "aggrettare" e "aggrettato", ma non ho trovato questi vocaboli in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "pettinature aggrettate" nel brano precedente?

Comment: A quanto pare *aggrettato* è un termine antiquato per i collari che si usavano nell'abbigliamento di uomini e donne: le pieghe possono richiamare un modo di acconciare i capelli. Cerca il termine in https://archive.org/stream/dizionariodieru47morogoog/dizionariodieru47morogoog_djvu.txt

Comment: @egreg: "Aggrettato" appare anche in uno dei testi riportati in [questo articolo](https://www.academia.edu/30076952/Memorie_di_Bettona_di_Pietro_Onofri): «Le Monache velate vestivano con Tonaca di Saja nera, soggolo **aggrettato**, e velo doppio in Capo, cioè sotto bianco, e sopra nero, che gli pendeva dietro sino alle natiche a modo di Cappucci, o Piramide»   (dalle *Memorie di Bettona* di Pietro Onofri).

Comment: E nello stesso testo di prima: «L’Imbiancheria più rimarchevole sono un Camige aggrettato, e due altri lisci».